# Creating an event subscription for Azure storage account in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create the following resources in Azure using **Terraform** and **Terraform provider for Azure**.

- Create a storage account for blob storage.
- Create an event subscription that will raise events on blob activity.

When running the terraform scripts i get the following error

> Error: Error creating/updating EventGrid Event Subscription
>   "evtFileReceived" (Scope
>   "/subscriptions/c17cf5ee-d3d7-4f64-b863-f2a4d6948594/resourceGroups/dominos-doodle"):
>   eventgrid.EventSubscriptionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
>   request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidRequest"
>   Message="The specified topic property does not match the expected
>   topic from the event subscription scope."

How shoud i fix it ?. Google search didn't gave any results.

The script that generated the error is as follows. The step that throwed the error is `terraform apply`

Obviously one way is to use the ARM templates to achieve this, but i am trying to see if it can be created using native Terraform scripts. I referred to [Terraform Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/eventgrid_event_subscription.html#webhook_endpoint) and created the following.

```
variable "inp_resource_group_name" { }
variable "inp_geo_location" { }
variable "inp_account_name" { }
variable "inp_az_subscription_id" { }
variable "inp_resource_group_id" { }

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "cave" {
  name                     = var.inp_account_name
  resource_group_name      = var.inp_resource_group_name
  location                 = var.inp_geo_location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "validName" {
  name                  = validName"
  resource_group_name   = var.inp_resource_group_name
  storage_account_name  = var.inp_account_name
  container_access_type = "blob"
}

resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "evtFileReceived" {
  name  = "evtFileReceived"
  scope = var.inp_resource_group_id
  topic_name="/subscriptions/${var.inp_az_subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.inp_resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{var.inp_account_name}"
  webhook_endpoint {
    url = "https://myendpoint.that.works.well.across.all.osi.layers"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just quick one, resource group attribute is not required in container block. Please remove it as it will throw an error.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and solved it by setting both the scope and topic_name to the storage account id. So in your example, I think this should work;

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "evtFileReceived" {
  name  = "evtFileReceived"
  scope = azurerm_storage_account.cave.id
  topic_name = azurerm_storage_account.cave.id
  webhook_endpoint {
    url = "https://myendpoint.that.works.well.across.all.osi.layers"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it indicates that the **topic_name** property in resource `azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription` does not match the expected topic from the event subscription **scope**.

In this case, the scope should be created at the storage account level as the topic is associated with a storage account resource. It will like this:

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "evtFileReceived" {
  name  = "evtFileReceived"
  scope = ${azurerm_storage_account.cave.id}
  topic_name="/subscriptions/${var.inp_az_subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.inp_resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{azurerm_storage_account.cave.name}"
  webhook_endpoint {
    url = "https://myendpoint.that.works.well.across.all.osi.layers"
  }
}
```

Or, refer to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3305#issuecomment-502095672), you could use the **scope** with the id of the
eventgrid topic.

> Realized that the resource group in this case is an art from a topic
>   type to subscribe and not a reference where to create the subscription
>   resource. It seems that "topic_name" and "resource_group_name" are
>   deprecated parameters. Use "scope" instead with the id of the
>   eventgrid topic.

It will like this:

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "example" {
  name                = "my-eventgrid-topic"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.default.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.default.name}"

}

resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "evtFileReceived" {
  name  = "evtFileReceived"
  scope = "${azurerm_eventgrid_topic.example.id}"

 webhook_endpoint {
        url = "https://myendpoint.that.works.well.across.all.osi.layers"
      }

}
```

Please let me know if this works or need further help.

Comment: Hi, 
In this case where does the event grid subscription / event grid topic tie to the storage account. My interest is to raise events when